# How can I use (one fragment + one activity + viewpager) to display multiple strings

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am basically doing a reading app with 18 subjects.

I need to shrink my project because I got one activity and 18 fragments that contains two Text views: one of them represent a normal String from strings.xml, and the other one represent a string from strings.xml with HTML attributes with images. I tried to build a setting for the users to control the font size and color and I failed because I ended up with 18 text views for titles and 18 text views for the threads.

I planned to do my project in just one fragment that contains just two text views; one for titles and the other one for the threads.

[Here is an image explaining my thought](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03nGm.jpg)

I figure out how to do the title because it just one string with out html attributes but when it came to doing both i failed

from the activity:

```
    public static Thread0_Fragment create(String mThreadTitle){
    Thread0_Fragment fragment = new Thread0_Fragment();
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putString(ARG_PAGE, mThreadTitle);
    fragment.setArguments(arg);
    return fragment;
}
```

from the fragment view pager adapter:

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Thread0_Fragment.create(getString(R.string.thread_18));
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: how two display the strings that will represent the HTML attributes the same way i did it for the titles?

Comment: Basically I want the threads and title changes with every slide with view pager

Comment: Set an onPageChangeListener to the ViewPager, set the title in onPageSelected.

Comment: you should use string-array instead and return Thread0_Fragment.create(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.threads)[position])

Comment: I have already set the onPageChangeListener  and I knew how two slide between pages .. one more thing I knew how to set all titles by returning multiple fragments in the adapter with the title strings.. but the thing that i strigleing with guys is how two set two text views as i explayed

Comment: why can make this Thread0_Fragment.create(Html.fromHtml(R.string.thread0)); happen